# maintain border integrity when there is add a right scroll bar

Tags: html, css

I want to make a table, without table tags. After a certain number of rows are added to the table body, a scroll bar should appear. But the problem is that when the vertical scroll bar appears, the lateral borders of the cells in the table body do not align with those in the header. What can I do to solve this?
The header has be fixed and the body of the table has to be scrollable.

Here is a sample code:

```css
.table-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.fixedheader {
  background-color: pink;
}

.table-header>* {
  color: rgb(76, 112, 121);
  padding: 0px 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 11px;
  /*margin: 0;*/
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  border-color: rgb(222,227,232);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0 0;
  line-height: 25px;
}

/* .account-body {
  overflow-y: auto;
} */

.all-entries {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.date {
  min-width: 80.2px;
  width: 5%;
}

.payee {
  min-width: 119px;
  width: 15%;
}

.category {
  min-width: 182.2px;
  width: 40%;
}

.memo {
  min-width: 122.2px;
  width: 25%
}

.outflow {
  min-width: 71.2px;
  width: 10%;
}

.inflow {
  min-width: 71.2px;
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="accout body">
  <div class="table-header fixedheader" >
    <h5 class="date">DATE</h5>
    <h5 class="payee">PAYEE</h5>
    <h5 class="category">CATEGORY</h5>
    <h5 class="memo">MEMO</h5>
    <h5 class="outflow">OUTFLOW</h5>
    <h5 class="inflow">INFLOW</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="all-entries">
    <div class="article-row">
      <div class="table-header">
        <h5 class="date">2017/12/12</h5>
        <h5 class="payee">Someone</h5>
        <h5 class="category">Somestuff</h5>
        <h5 class="memo">Nothing special</h5>
        <h5 class="outflow">200</h5>
        <h5 class="inflow">0</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="table-header">
        <h5 class="date">2017/12/12</h5>
        <h5 class="payee">Someone</h5>
        <h5 class="category">Somestuff</h5>
        <h5 class="memo">Nothing special</h5>
        <h5 class="outflow">200</h5>
        <h5 class="inflow">0</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="table-header">
        <h5 class="date">2017/12/12</h5>
        <h5 class="payee">Someone</h5>
        <h5 class="category">Somestuff</h5>
        <h5 class="memo">Nothing special</h5>
        <h5 class="outflow">200</h5>
        <h5 class="inflow">0</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="table-header">
        <h5 class="date">2017/12/12</h5>
        <h5 class="payee">Someone</h5>
        <h5 class="category">Somestuff</h5>
        <h5 class="memo">Nothing special</h5>
        <h5 class="outflow">200</h5>
        <h5 class="inflow">0</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="table-header">
        <h5 class="date">2017/12/12</h5>
        <h5 class="payee">Someone</h5>
        <h5 class="category">Somestuff</h5>
        <h5 class="memo">Nothing special</h5>
        <h5 class="outflow">200</h5>
        <h5 class="inflow">0</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="table-header">
        <h5 class="date">2017/12/12</h5>
        <h5 class="payee">Someone</h5>
        <h5 class="category">Somestuff</h5>
        <h5 class="memo">Nothing special</h5>
        <h5 class="outflow">200</h5>
        <h5 class="inflow">0</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="table-header">
        <h5 class="date">2017/12/12</h5>
        <h5 class="payee">Someone</h5>
        <h5 class="category">Somestuff</h5>
        <h5 class="memo">Nothing special</h5>
        <h5 class="outflow">200</h5>
        <h5 class="inflow">0</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="table-header">
        <h5 class="date">2017/12/12</h5>
        <h5 class="payee">Someone</h5>
        <h5 class="category">Somestuff</h5>
        <h5 class="memo">Nothing special</h5>
        <h5 class="outflow">200</h5>
        <h5 class="inflow">0</h5>
      </div><div class="table-header">
        <h5 class="date">2017/12/12</h5>
        <h5 class="payee">Someone</h5>
        <h5 class="category">Somestuff</h5>
        <h5 class="memo">Nothing special</h5>
        <h5 class="outflow">200</h5>
        <h5 class="inflow">0</h5>
      </div><div class="table-header">
        <h5 class="date">2017/12/12</h5>
        <h5 class="payee">Someone</h5>
        <h5 class="category">Somestuff</h5>
        <h5 class="memo">Nothing special</h5>
        <h5 class="outflow">200</h5>
        <h5 class="inflow">0</h5>
      </div><div class="table-header">
        <h5 class="date">2017/12/12</h5>
        <h5 class="payee">Someone</h5>
        <h5 class="category">Somestuff</h5>
        <h5 class="memo">Nothing special</h5>
        <h5 class="outflow">200</h5>
        <h5 class="inflow">0</h5>
      </div><div class="table-header">
        <h5 class="date">2017/12/12</h5>
        <h5 class="payee">Someone</h5>
        <h5 class="category">Somestuff</h5>
        <h5 class="memo">Nothing special</h5>
        <h5 class="outflow">200</h5>
        <h5 class="inflow">0</h5>
      </div><div class="table-header">
        <h5 class="date">2017/12/12</h5>
        <h5 class="payee">Someone</h5>
        <h5 class="category">Somestuff</h5>
        <h5 class="memo">Nothing special</h5>
        <h5 class="outflow">200</h5>
        <h5 class="inflow">0</h5>
      </div><div class="table-header">
        <h5 class="date">2017/12/12</h5>
        <h5 class="payee">Someone</h5>
        <h5 class="category">Somestuff</h5>
        <h5 class="memo">Nothing special</h5>
        <h5 class="outflow">200</h5>
        <h5 class="inflow">0</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can customize scrollbar of the table try this :

```css
.table-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  /*background-color: lightpink;*/
  height: 26px;
  margin-top: 0px;

}

.table-header>* {
  color: rgb(76, 112, 121);
  padding: 0px 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 11px;
  /*margin: 0;*/
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  border-color: rgb(222,227,232);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0 0;
  line-height: 25px;
}

/* .account-body {
  overflow-y: auto;
} */

.all-entries {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.date {
  min-width: 80.2px;
  width: 5%;
}

.payee {
  min-width: 119px;
  width: 15%;
}

.category {
  min-width: 182.2px;
  width: 40%;
}

.memo {
  min-width: 122.2px;
  width: 25%
}

.outflow {
  min-width: 71.2px;
  width: 10%;
}

.inflow {
  min-width: 71.2px;
  width: 10%;
}

/* costume scroll bar with 1px width */
.all-entries::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.all-entries::-webkit-scrollbar
{
 width: 2px;
 background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.all-entries::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
 background-color: black;
 border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="accout body">
  <div class="table-header fixedheader" >
    <h5 class="date">DATE</h5>
    <h5 class="payee">PAYEE</h5>
    <h5 class="category">CATEGORY</h5>
    <h5 class="memo">MEMO</h5>
    <h5 class="outflow">OUTFLOW</h5>
    <h5 class="inflow">INFLOW</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="all-entries">
    <div class="article-row">
      <div class="table-header">
        <h5 class="date">2017/12/12</h5>
        <h5 class="payee">Someone</h5>
        <h5 class="category">Somestuff</h5>
        <h5 class="memo">Nothing special</h5>
        <h5 class="outflow">200</h5>
        <h5 class="inflow">0</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="table-header">
        <h5 class="date">2017/12/12</h5>
        <h5 class="payee">Someone</h5>
        <h5 class="category">Somestuff</h5>
        <h5 class="memo">Nothing special</h5>
        <h5 class="outflow">200</h5>
        <h5 class="inflow">0</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="table-header">
        <h5 class="date">2017/12/12</h5>
        <h5 class="payee">Someone</h5>
        <h5 class="category">Somestuff</h5>
        <h5 class="memo">Nothing special</h5>
        <h5 class="outflow">200</h5>
        <h5 class="inflow">0</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="table-header">
        <h5 class="date">2017/12/12</h5>
        <h5 class="payee">Someone</h5>
        <h5 class="category">Somestuff</h5>
        <h5 class="memo">Nothing special</h5>
        <h5 class="outflow">200</h5>
        <h5 class="inflow">0</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="table-header">
        <h5 class="date">2017/12/12</h5>
        <h5 class="payee">Someone</h5>
        <h5 class="category">Somestuff</h5>
        <h5 class="memo">Nothing special</h5>
        <h5 class="outflow">200</h5>
        <h5 class="inflow">0</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="table-header">
        <h5 class="date">2017/12/12</h5>
        <h5 class="payee">Someone</h5>
        <h5 class="category">Somestuff</h5>
        <h5 class="memo">Nothing special</h5>
        <h5 class="outflow">200</h5>
        <h5 class="inflow">0</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="table-header">
        <h5 class="date">2017/12/12</h5>
        <h5 class="payee">Someone</h5>
        <h5 class="category">Somestuff</h5>
        <h5 class="memo">Nothing special</h5>
        <h5 class="outflow">200</h5>
        <h5 class="inflow">0</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="table-header">
        <h5 class="date">2017/12/12</h5>
        <h5 class="payee">Someone</h5>
        <h5 class="category">Somestuff</h5>
        <h5 class="memo">Nothing special</h5>
        <h5 class="outflow">200</h5>
        <h5 class="inflow">0</h5>
      </div><div class="table-header">
        <h5 class="date">2017/12/12</h5>
        <h5 class="payee">Someone</h5>
        <h5 class="category">Somestuff</h5>
        <h5 class="memo">Nothing special</h5>
        <h5 class="outflow">200</h5>
        <h5 class="inflow">0</h5>
      </div><div class="table-header">
        <h5 class="date">2017/12/12</h5>
        <h5 class="payee">Someone</h5>
        <h5 class="category">Somestuff</h5>
        <h5 class="memo">Nothing special</h5>
        <h5 class="outflow">200</h5>
        <h5 class="inflow">0</h5>
      </div><div class="table-header">
        <h5 class="date">2017/12/12</h5>
        <h5 class="payee">Someone</h5>
        <h5 class="category">Somestuff</h5>
        <h5 class="memo">Nothing special</h5>
        <h5 class="outflow">200</h5>
        <h5 class="inflow">0</h5>
      </div><div class="table-header">
        <h5 class="date">2017/12/12</h5>
        <h5 class="payee">Someone</h5>
        <h5 class="category">Somestuff</h5>
        <h5 class="memo">Nothing special</h5>
        <h5 class="outflow">200</h5>
        <h5 class="inflow">0</h5>
      </div><div class="table-header">
        <h5 class="date">2017/12/12</h5>
        <h5 class="payee">Someone</h5>
        <h5 class="category">Somestuff</h5>
        <h5 class="memo">Nothing special</h5>
        <h5 class="outflow">200</h5>
        <h5 class="inflow">0</h5>
      </div><div class="table-header">
        <h5 class="date">2017/12/12</h5>
        <h5 class="payee">Someone</h5>
        <h5 class="category">Somestuff</h5>
        <h5 class="memo">Nothing special</h5>
        <h5 class="outflow">200</h5>
        <h5 class="inflow">0</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hiding the scroll bar is plausible, but isn't there a way to do it without hiding it?